Ordinal regression / 2-step model
I unfortunately have to be somewhat ambiguous with details but hopefully I can provide enough general information to ask a relevant question with enough content that readers might be able to guide me to some useful material. I am not formally trained in statistics, but try to do my best at doing reasonably sensible things and seek the help of statisticians where I can/afford. Anyway..... I have cross-sectional survey data (advertised via social media) which collected information on demographic variables, other variables of explanatory interest (some continuous, some categorical), and also asked a set of questions which are the primary response variables of interest. The scale for these response variable questions is the following (each question is a separate construct - they are not summed or averaged into any sum score or formal measurement model):
1 = No problem at all
2 = Mild
3 = Moderate
4 = Severe
Let's say I was interested in assessing the relationship between two explanatory variables (one continuous, and one categorical with 3 levels) and an ordinal response, then as I understand, I could fit a proportional odds ordinal logistic regression to model the relationship between the predictors and response, however, the response scale to me seems more like a 2-step process. That is:
Step/model 1 = Is the problem present/absent?
Step/model 2 = If the problem is present, how severe is it?
So as I see it, I have a few options:

Just model all ordinal response categories with a PO ordinal regression (or some alternative that relaxes PO assumption if required/necessary)
First model present/absent with a binary logistic regression, and then model the mild/moderate/severe response outcomes with a PO ordinal regression (is this reasonable or are there any problems with 'using the data twice' etc.?
Alternatively, are there any 2-step models where I can jointly estimate presence/absence and then severity conditioned on the problem being present but which actually models an ordinal response?

If anyone can point me toward any accessible material/reading/blogs or models that they think might be useful that would be great.
Many thanks in advance
